# How to connect a different physical interface to the VPN tun0?

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

I'd like to allow a computer connected to a physical interface to be directly connected to the VPN.

- Routing mode VPN network: `172.16.0.0/24`
- internal LAN: `192.168.0.1/24` (irrelevant?)

With the current architecture, the WORKSTATION sends an ARP I can see in the **eno1** interface but no reply.

- eno1:
  [image: arps]

---

[image: diagram]

1. Which IP the WORKSTATION can use? I set up a random .222 I'm sure it's unused.
2. IP forwarding is already set
3. eno1 has a random IP 10.50.0.1 (never used)

Somehow I need to route all the packets (ARP included) from **eno1** to **tun0**.
Do I need to bridge them?

```sh
172.16.0.0/24 via 172.16.0.129 dev tun0 metric 101 
172.16.0.128/25 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.131

#private LAN of the VPN server to be accessible from the openvpn clients
192.168.111.0/24 via 172.16.0.129 dev tun0 metric 101

10.50.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.50.0.200 metric 105
```

- I'd like to avoid NAT unless it's mandatory..

Comment: OpenVPN clients do not generally share their vpn tunnel; they're not designed to be vpn *routers*. Once the vpn connection is established, it will not be able to maintain connections with your workstation.

Comment: What can I do then? The client's private LAN subnet is already shared among all the VPN clients, same for the server's private lan subnet. From the workstation, I want to access the VPN server's private lan subnet (192.168.111.0/24). Which ip/mask and gateway must I set for my workstation?

Comment: OpenVPN connections can't be shared. Each workstation would need to run OpenVPN client and have it's own tunnel to the private network.

Comment: I don't understand, of course they can be shared, that's the point of a site-to-site routing vpn. (https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/)